# How to query for null values in json field type postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a json type field in postgresql. However I can't select rows where specific field is null:

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   json_array_elements(
  '[{"name": "Toby", "occupation": "Software Engineer"},
    {"name": "Zaphod", "occupation": "Galactic President"} ,
{"name2": "Zaphod", "occupation2": null} ]'  ) AS elem
where elem#>'{occupation2}' is null
```

This should work but I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json #> boolean
LINE 6: where elem#>'{occupation2}' is null
```

Answer (score 85):

you can use the fact that `elem->'occupation2'` returns string `null` of type `json`, so your query will be:

```
select
    *
from  json_array_elements(
  '[{"name": "Toby", "occupation": "Software Engineer"},
    {"name": "Zaphod", "occupation": "Galactic President"} ,
    {"name2": "Zaphod", "occupation2": null} ]'
) as elem
where (elem->'occupation2')::text = 'null'

{"name2": "Zaphod", "occupation2": null}
```

If you want to get all elements where value is `null` in JSON or key doesn't exists, you can just do:

```
select
    *
from  json_array_elements(
  '[{"name": "Toby", "occupation": "Software Engineer"},
    {"name": "Zaphod", "occupation": "Galactic President"} ,
    {"name2": "Zaphod", "occupation2": null} ]'
) as elem
where (elem->>'occupation2') is null

{"name": "Toby", "occupation": "Software Engineer"}
{"name": "Zaphod", "occupation": "Galactic President"}
{"name2": "Zaphod", "occupation2": null}
```

Comment: This worked for me in plpgsql as well. I had to place the json extract in brackets before checking if it is null.

Comment: Maybe the associativity rules were obvious to others (and maybe this is what @Imraan was saying as well), but I didn't realize the importance of parentheses before casting to text. Meaning, `elem->'occupation2'::text` does not work but (as you have), `(elem->'occupation2')::text` does work.

Comment: The second example worked for me. I was missing the parentheses.

Comment: Hi @roman, Could you share any postgres documentation stating this behaviour?

Answer (score 15):

If you are searching for a null value within a json-blob you might want to consider using the function `json_typeof(json)` that was introduced in Postgres 9.4:

```
INSERT INTO table
  VALUES ('{ "value": "some", "object": {"int": 1, "nullValue": null}}');

SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE json_typeof(json->'object'->'nullValue') = 'null';
```

This will result in you finding your entry for the null value.

Hope this helps!

Reference:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE

Answer (score 2):

The answers from @roman-pekar and @mraxus were helpful but I was unsatisfied without the ability to clearly distinguish undefined and null... so, I came up with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnull (element json)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
  SELECT (element IS NOT NULL) AND (element::text = 'null');
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;

select isnull('{"test":null}'::json->'test'); -- returns t
select isnull('{"test":"notnull"}'::json->'test'); -- returns f
select isnull('{"toot":"testundefined"}'::json->'test'); -- returns null
```

@a_horse_with_no_name also pointed out the additional jsonb operator `?` introduced in postgresql version 9.4:

```sql
SELECT '{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb ? 'b'
```

Comment: To distinguish between null and a non-existing key, you can use the `?` operator to test if the key is present.

Answer (score 2):

Use dbeaver editor for this, it is working there.

```sql
SELECT * FROM json_array_elements('[{"name": "Toby", "occupation": "Software Engineer"},{"name": "Zaphod", "occupation": "Galactic President"},{"name2":"Zaphod","occupation2":null}]') AS elem
where elem#>'{occupation2}') IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

For a specific JSON value, cast expression to `jsonb` and compare it to `'null'::jsonb`.

Here, the objective is to find an object that has the key `occupation2` and value JSON `null`. The comparison must not confuse the existence of the key with the value.

Adapting the original:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM json_array_elements(
      '[{"name": "Toby", "occupation": "Software Engineer"},
        {"name": "Zaphod", "occupation": "Galactic President"},
        {"name2": "Zaphod", "occupation2": null}]'
      ) AS elem
    WHERE (elem#>'{occupation2}')::jsonb = 'null'::jsonb
;
```