# How to get only those rows of a Postgresql stored json, that match a schema

Tags: json, postgresql

Assume a Postgresql table which contains a JSON column. Now how do I get only those table rows which match a certain 'JSON-Schema'?

I was hoping that

`select category#>'{Kategorie}' from dataset where category#>'{Kategorie}' is not null`

would only get me those rows which match the {Kategorie} Schema.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422640/how-to-query-for-null-values-in-json-field-type-postgresql.

Comment: @dommage Thank you, that was helpful, almost on track

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the pointer provided by @dommage, the syntax actually is

```
select category#>'{Kategorie}' from dataset where (category#>'{Kategorie}') is not null
```

The parantheses arround the json-extraction operation in the where clause are crucial.