# Get records where json column key is null

Tags: json, postgresql

I have table `users` with json column `details`.

I want to fetch all user records where details["email"] is null or email key doesn't exist.

This doesn't work:

`SELECT users.* FROM users where details->'email' IS NOT NULL;`

`ERROR:  operator does not exist: json -> boolean`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

use brackets `()`. Looks like compiler tries to see it like `details->('email' IS NOT NULL)`. So you can fix it like this:

```
select *
from users
where (details->'email') is not null
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/155d9/6)</kbd>**

actually, to get records where *details["email"] is null or email key doesn't exist*, you can use this query:

```
select *
from users
where (details->>'email') is null
```

as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426902/1744834).

Comment: Exactly - brackets were missing. Thanks.

Comment: Just a word for posterity: brackets isn't needed on Postgres version starting from 9.5.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the `->>` operator for that:

```
select *
from users
where (details->>'email') is not null
```

Because the `->` operator returns `'null'::json` (and not sql `NULL`) if the key is exists but with a json null value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/76ec4/2

Comment: Actually the problem was with missing brackets as answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23912628/298554

Comment: I tried both with `->` and `->>` - it always return correct records.

Comment: @morgoth That was just the syntactical problem. If the one wants to treat `'null'::json` values the same as sql's `NULL` they should use the `->>` operator over the `->`. See the difference in my fiddle.

Comment: Missing brackets was the problem for me too.