# Better/shorter way to check inexistence of JSONB key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Where `data` is JSONB column, I want to check if the key exists, normally I use:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE length(data->>'fingerprint_id') IS NULL;
```

Is there any better/shorter way to do this? since other alternative give incorrect result:

```
> SELECT id FROM users WHERE data->>'fingerprint_id' IS NULL;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ->> boolean
LINE 1: SELECT id FROM users WHERE data->>'fingerprint_id' IS NULL;
                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

> SELECT id FROM users WHERE data->>'fingerprint_id' = '';
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an explicit operator (`?`) for this purpose:

```
where data_jsonb ? 'key'
```

But be aware, that this might cause [some DB abstraction layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573778/postgresql-jsonb-and-jdbc) (f.ex. JDBC) to falsely recognize `?` as an input parameter's placeholder.

As a workaround, you could use the `jsonb_exists(json, text)` function directly (but your code will then depend on an undocumented function), or define a similar operator for this, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27580137/1499698).

More details about the `(data ->> 'key') IS NULL` syntax [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911740/get-records-where-json-column-key-is-null).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I just need to enclose the query with `()` before `IS NULL`

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE (data->>'fingerprint_id') IS NULL;
```

Comment: Correct, it's because the binding strength of `IS NULL` is stronger than `->>`.