# Ruby Rails, JSON - match results if key exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

The set up is ruby on rails, in a postgres database.  The table is called `line_sources` and a JSON column is called `names`.  I want to return all rows where the `names` column contains a key called `away_names`.  I'm trying this but they fail:

```
LineSource.where("names -> 'away_names'")
```

and

```
LineSource.where("names ->> 'away_names' = '%'")
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this :

```
where("(names->'away_names') is not null")
```

Comment: that works.  how did you know parenthesis are needed around names->'away_names'

Comment: googling "postgresql json key exist" then using things from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911740/get-records-where-json-column-key-is-null

Answer (score 5):

You can use `#>` to get the JSON object at that path.

```
where("(names #>'{away_names}') is not null")
```

Basic key operators to query the JSON objects :

- `#>` : Get the JSON object at that path
- `->>` : Get the JSON object at that path as text
- `{obj, n}` : Get the nth item in that object