# Calculate JSONB Array Length Using PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I'm running the latest version of PostgreSQL `9.4.5-1.pgdg14.04+1`, and am attempting to calculate the length of a JSONB array using the `JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH` function as described in the [PostgreSQL 9.4 Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

Here is the exact query I'm attempting to run:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH('["hi","ho"]'::jsonb) AS length
```

When I run that query, I would expect to be returned a value of `2`, but instead am encountering the error: `ERROR: function json_array_length(jsonb) does not exist`

Am I missing something very obvious in the documentation? It specifically states you may call `JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH` passing either a `json` or `jsonb` data-type. I'm explicitly casting to `jsonb` so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, or would someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE: I Mis-Read The Documentation**

I should have been calling `JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH`, not `JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH`. Notice the "B" after "JSON". Thanks guys.

Comment: I cannot find where "It specifically states you may call JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH passing either a json or jsonb data-type" - could you cite it literally?.

Comment: Must be a misunderstanding. [The manual says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html): `json_array_length(json)  jsonb_array_length(jsonb)`.

Comment: as @klin says, I think you are misreading the documentation, it shows that you need to call either `json_` or `jsonb_` versions of the functions depending upon datatype

Comment: WOW you're right. I mis-read the documentation, I didn't notice the difference between the names of the functions themselves.

Comment: Is there a different function for when the column type is 'jsonb[]'?  the values look like "{1,2}" and the column type is jsonb[].

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
SELECT jsonb_array_length('["question","solved"]') AS length;
```

or

```
SELECT json_array_length('["question","solved"]') AS length;
```

Comment: For me, the function name had to be caps for it to work (windows, perhaps?) JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH/JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH

Comment: Note that this won't work if the array is null. See here for more details about how to handle (or filter out) such cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426902/997940

Comment: In my case I had to intitally convert to jsonb or json respectively.