# How to check if a JSON stored in a Postgres column has a key after a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I tried something like this...

```
result = User.includes(:detail).where("detail.strings->'the_key') IS NOT NULL")
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I want to join `User` to `Detail` and then check the column `strings` in the table `Detail` to see if the json stored in `strings` has `the_key`. That doesn't work. I also tried use `strings->` but that didn't work as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422640/how-to-query-for-null-values-in-json-field-type-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
User.joins(:detail).where("detail.strings ->> 'the_key' IS NOT NULL")
```